# How to blit a string in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am coding a game in which the player enters its name, and I'd like to blit it on the screen.

Heres how I take the name (name is a string that is put in global in the following function):

```
while player_name_screen:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    print(name)
                    menu_screen = False
                    player_name_screen = False
                    game_animation = True
                    enemy_animation = True
                    standing = True
                else:
                    name += event.unicode
                    name_text = game_font.render(name, True, (125, 156, 255))
        win.blit(name_text, (500, 500))            
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(fps)
```

And here's how I wanna blit player's name (following code is in a fonction, that is called in my main loop):

```
if game_animation:
        win.blit(name_text, (100, 300))
```

But nothing appears on the screen, and when I print this in the shell, It appears like this : `<Surface(63x50x32 SW)>`
How can I make it blit correctly on the screen ? I looked already for similar questions but couldn't find one that answers my problem.
Thanks for your help

Edit : 
Heres the whole thing that is needed for this to work:

```
name = ""
name_text = game_font.render('', True, (255, 255, 255))

def input_player_name():
    global menu_screen
    global game_animation
    global enemy_animation
    global standing
    global deluxe_or_not
    global name
    global name_text
    #print("Enter player's name")
    player_name_screen = True
    win.blit(playerNameImg, (0, 0))
    while player_name_screen:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    print(name)
                    menu_screen = False
                    player_name_screen = False
                    game_animation = True
                    enemy_animation = True
                    standing = True
                    imperial_march.play()
                    if "deluxe.ver" in name:
                        print("deluxe.ver.exe")
                        deluxe_or_not = 1
                else:
                    name += event.unicode
                    #print(name)
                    name_text = game_font.render(name, True, (125, 156, 255))
        win.blit(name_text, (500, 500))            
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(fps)

def rwg():
    if game_animation:
        win.blit(name_text, (100, 300))
        print(name_text)

run = True
while run:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
               if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and menu_screen == True:
                    input_player_name()

     rwg()
```

Comment: `name_text` local variable or a variable in global namespace? *"following code is in a fonction"* - Where it the function? Where and how do you call the function? What are the a arguments of the function? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont update the screen. You only update the screen in the `input_player_name` function, but when you get the name and is stops getting called, there is not update to update the screen.

So add `pygame.display.update()` at the end of the loop

```
run = True
while run:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
               if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and menu_screen == True:
                    input_player_name()

     rwg()
     pygame.display.update()
```

then you can can get rid of the one in `input_player_name` as the one in the loop happens very frame and you dont want to update the screen twice in a frame

Comment: If I remove the display update in ```input_player_name```and add it after rwg(), it freezes the screen when I call the fonction for player name
Edit : I forgot to say that of course display updates in the rwg function, the rest of my program (around 1k lines) is working great

Comment: @bappi My bad, didn't realise you had another loop in `input_player_name()`. Which is something i wouldn't recomend. But it works so keep the `pygame.display.update()`  in the function and everything will work fine

Comment: Dont worry, and it still doesn't work, Im just trying to blit the name and it still doesn't appear on the screen.

Comment: @bappi So, i ran your code, and it works for me, i did get rid of  `and menu_screen == True:` and moved the text from `(500,500)` to `(200,200)` and it worked, i guess just make sure your screen is big enough, the background colour is not the same and `menu_screen = True`. If it still doesn't work, post all of your code.

Comment: I see, I wasn't clear. I'm trying to blit the name once I exit the ``input_player_name()```, which is ``ìf game_animation : win.blit(name, (100, 300)) ```. I don't know if there's a way to show a video if what I'm trying to do is hard to understand.

Comment: Yeah, once i press enter after inputting name, it displays name in that area and prints the surface, it works for me, Could you post all of your code

Comment: Ok Im just so dumb, I wrote the line for blitting the name before the line for blitting the background. I just thought of changing this now, and of course it wasn't gonna work. Thanks for trying to helping me tho !

Comment: It happens to the best of us. Glad you fixed it

Comment: is there a way to close the question ? Now that I got the answer